# Replace select option list value of other select box

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <select class="main">
         <option value="1" selected>One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
         <option value="3">Three</option>
         <option value="4">Four</option>
         <option value="5">Five</option>
      </select>
   </li>
   <li>
      <select >
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2">Two</option>
         <option value="3">Three</option>
         <option value="4">Four</option>
         <option value="5">Five</option>
      </select>
   </li>
   <li>
      <select >
         <option value="1">One</option>
         <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
         <option
            value="3">Three</option>
         <option value="4">Four</option>
         <option
            value="5">Five</option>
      </select>
   </li>
</ul>
<li>
   <select class="main">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
   </select>
</li>
<li>
   <select >
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
   </select>
</li>
<li>
   <select >
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2" selected >Two</option>
      <option
         value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option
         value="5">Five</option>
   </select>
</li>
</ul>
```

IN this code when i select 2 in first option then all option value where 1 is previously selected should be replace by 1

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="main">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="child">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**CODE**

```
$('#main').change(function() {
    $('#child').val(this.value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main').change(function(){
    var _choosed = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    if (_choosed == '2'){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('select:not(.main) option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true)
;
    }
});
```